# Not able to run selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable
>   to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox
>   console output: Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
>   1484800955114 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on 
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
>     ... 33 more

**I am using firefox of version:50.1.0
selenium version: 2.53.1
TestNG; 6.9.9**

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your  selenium libraries to latest i.e. `Selenium 3.0.1` as  your current libraries doesn't support `Firefox 50`

also download `gecko` driver from [Here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Use `gecko` driver to run your script in `firefox` -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:/Application/geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```